# Text path label on d3 force layout - chrome issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js

This is the know problem in chrome. I tried multiple solutions.

But my bad luck and understanding i am not able to fix.

Could someone help me. I spent lot of time. could not resolve this. Label this links not working in chrome

```
var nodes ;
var links;
var linkNodeMap = {};
var width = window.innerWidth-30,
    height = window.innerHeight-140,
    root = {
  "nodes": [
    {
      "type": "S",
      "id": "1",
      "name": "1001"
    },
    {
      "type": "S",
      "id": "2",
      "name": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": "10.10.0.5",
      "name": "h5"
    },
    {
      "id": "10.10.0.3",
      "name": "h3"
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "source": 1,
      "p1":3,
      "p2":4,
      "index":0,
      "target": 0
    },
    {
      "source": 1,
      "p1":5,
      "p2":6,
      "index":0,
      "target": 0
    },
    {
      "source": 1,
      "p1":3,
      "p2":4,
      "index":0,
      "target": 2
    },
    {
      "source": 1,
      "p1":3,
      "p2":4,
      "index":0,
      "target": 3
    }
  ]
};
document.getElementById("refresh").disabled  = false;
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .linkDistance(100)
    .charge(-120)
    .gravity(.03)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .style("border", "1px solid black")
    .attr("height", height);
var g = svg.append("g");
var link = g.selectAll("path");
var node = svg.selectAll(".node");
var sourcePortText = g.selectAll("text.label");
var destinationPortText = g.selectAll("text.label");
function updateLinkCount (link) {
      var linkcount = getLinkCount(link);
      if(linkcount == undefined)
          linkcount = 0;
        linkcount = linkcount + 1;  
        link.index = linkcount;
        linkNodeMap[getKey(link)] = linkcount;
}
function getLinkCount(link) {
   isAvaiable = linkNodeMap[link.source.id + '-' + link.target.id];
    if(isAvaiable != undefined)
        return isAvaiable
    return linkNodeMap[link.target.id + '-' + link.source.id];
}
function getKey(link) {
   isAvaiable = linkNodeMap[link.source.id + '-' + link.target.id];
    if(isAvaiable != undefined)
        return link.source.id + '-' + link.target.id
    return link.target.id + '-' + link.source.id;
}
function update() {
  nodes = root.nodes;
  links = root.links;
  // Restart the force layout.
  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

  // Update links.
  link = link.data(links, function(d) { 
      return d.source.id + '-' + d.p1 + '-'  + d.target.id + '-' +d.p2; });
  link.exit().remove();
  link.enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("id", function(d) { 
      return d.source.id + '-' + d.p1 + '-'  + d.target.id + '-' +d.p2; });
  links.forEach(function(link) {
      updateLinkCount(link);
  });

  // Update nodes.
  node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });
  node.exit().remove();
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag);
  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 20)
      .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; });
  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
  node.select("circle")
      .style("fill", color);
  node.select("text")
     .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  sourcePortText = sourcePortText.data(links, function(d) {
      return d.source.id + '-' + d.p1 + '-'  + d.target.id + '-' +d.p2;})
  sourcePortText.enter().append("text")
      .attr("dy", 4)
      .attr("font-size", 10)
      .attr("fill", "black")
      .append("textPath")
      .attr("startOffset","25%")
      .attr("class", "textPath")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return '#' + d.source.id + '-' + d.p1 + '-'  + d.target.id + '-' +d.p2;})
      .text(function(d) {  return d.p1 });

  sourcePortText.exit().remove();
  destinationPortText = destinationPortText.data(links, function(d) {
       return d.source.id + '-' + d.p1 + '-'  + d.target.id + '-' +d.p2;})
  destinationPortText.enter().append("text")
       .attr("class", "label")
       .attr("dy", 4)
       .attr("font-size", 10)
       .attr("fill", "black")
       .append("textPath")
       .attr("class", "textPath")
       .attr("startOffset","75%")
       .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return '#' + d.source.id + '-' + d.p1 + '-'  + d.target.id + '-' +d.p2;})
       .text(function(d) {  return d.p2;});
   destinationPortText.exit().remove();
}
function tick() {
  link.attr("d", linkArc);
  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  sourcePortText.attr("x",function(d){ return xpos(d.source, d.target);  });
  sourcePortText.attr("y",function(d){ return ypos(d.source, d.target); });
      svg.selectAll(".textPath").attr("xlink:href",
         function(d) {
            return "#"+d.source.id + '-' + d.p1 + '-'  + d.target.id + '-' +d.p2;
         })
  destinationPortText.attr("x",function(d){ return xpos(d.target, d.source); });
  destinationPortText.attr("y",function(d){ return ypos(d.target, d.source); });
}
function linkArc(d) {
   var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
   dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
   dr = 0;
   var linkCount = getLinkCount(d);
   if(linkCount > 1) {
       dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
       // if there are multiple links between these two nodes, we need generate different dr for each path
       dr = dr/(1 + (1/linkCount) * (linkCount - d.index));
   }
   return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}
function xpos(s, t) {
   var angle = Math.atan2(t.y - s.y, t.x - s.x);
   return 35 * Math.cos(angle) + s.x;
};
function ypos(s, t) {
    var angle = Math.atan2(t.y - s.y, t.x - s.x);
    return 35 * Math.sin(angle) + s.y;
};
function color(d) {
  return d.type == 'S' ? "#c6dbef": "#fd8d3c";
 }
function refresh() {
  linkNodeMap = {};
  update();
}
 update();
```

My fildle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pkolanda/Lmdag990/6/

Comment: Found the issue. I had to remove the x and y attribute for sourcePortText and destinationPortText in the tick.